# How to design a transimpedance amplifier that can adjust to large voltage swings?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, photodiode

I am making a photodiode sensor based on one show in the image below which I got from [this research article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325028451_Affordable_Bimodal_Optical_Sensors_to_Spread_the_Use_of_Automated_Insect_Monitoring). The problem I run into with my photodiode sensor is that variations in sunlight create amplitude swings that are too large. The circuit shown claims to be able to solve this issue.

How does this sunlight adjustment work, and what is this type of circuit called?
[image: nce]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's can be described as a **log-responding AGC linear-optical TIA PD detector.**

AGC: Automatic gain control
TIA: Transimpedance Amp.
PD: Photo Diode

The negative feedback voltage controls the collector current to shunt the PD current and increase the gain when the output (pin 7) rises above  2.5V then Vbe is reduced with Ic shunt and thus higher gain.

The inputs are all biased to Vref=Vcc/2.

The PD's have a negative linear gain but the output is integrated towards the the average voltage of Vcc/2.  Q1 has a log Ic vs Vbe response.

Thus the TIA has a wide dynamic range with a long time constant (R1C5=5.6ms) and a linear response at fast response (R2C1=125ns) for small signals.

Answer (score 1):

Let someone else put an "inventor's name" to this.

IC3A is an integrator whose response is slow enough that high-frequency currents from photodiodes do not take this path. However, for low frequencies (and DC too) the integrator provides a current via TR1 that sucks photocurrent to **GND**. The inverting input of IC3B is maintained at a DC potential of **REF**, and no DC current flows through R2. Output voltage of IC3B is maintained at **REF** DC potential.

Higher frequency photocurrents flow through R2, and generate an output voltage at IC3B's output: a standard transimpedance amplifier. TR1 doesn't interfere with these higher-frequency currents - only DC current flows from collector to emitter. And TR1's collector impedance is much higher than R2, so transimpedance AC gain is keyed to R2's value alone. DC collector current in TR1 is equal to photocurrent from daylight.